# Rewire polarized power receptacle that is installed backwards

Tags: electrical, rewire

The extension of the house I just bought seems to have the US 120V recpeticals wired backwards. The large blade tests hot and the small blade tests neutral. This and a bunch of other issues where found during the home inspection. Given some of the craziness in the house, I am a little worried that there is more to it than simply being wired backwards. In addition to my general wariness, I have tried plugging in a number of things and none of them work.

I guess I have two questions. What typical device in a house should work in an incorrectly polarized outlet? Can I simply turn off the power and flip the wires?

Comment: But which wires?

Comment: Plugging in devices is a poor way to test wiring faults. You risk damaging your devices, damaging yourself, starting a fire, who knows. At mininum acquire a tool designed for actually performing these tests, such as a proper [volt-/multimeter](https://www.google.com/search?q=voltmeter) rated at appropriate AC voltages, and be safe.

Comment: Is there any home appliance with a plug that _won't_ work if the wires are backwards?  Aside from safety issues, is there anything that just won't come on or work properly?  Doesn't seem like a valid test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What typical device in a house should work in an incorrectly polarized outlet?

Any standard lamp should still work. The screwshell will now be "hot" and the center tab will be neutral.

> Can I simply turn off the power and flip the wires?

It sounds like you might have to rewire several outlets. But by all means the first thing to do would be to turn off the circuit.

Good luck!

Comment: That is what I thought abut the lamp. Looks like I have a bigger issue. My voltage detector says onlybone slot is live, but my multimeter does not detect any voltage difference between the two slots (or the ground).

Comment: Yes sounds like a broke wire somewhere. Something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Those contact voltage detectors will sometimes false from induction. (In other words, a live wire is running near a dead wire.) Doublecheck your multimeter on a known live circuit to be sure you don't have a dead battery.

Comment: @StrongBad A voltmeter between neutral and ground will generally read 0 or close to it. I'd use a proper meter to test, but more importantly, I wouldn't test at all in your shoes, I would hire an electrician. For example, are you sure the wires are swapped, or is it that hot is broken and that neutral branch is shorted to hot somewhere down the line, not tripping breakers due to other wiring faults? You don't know, and you don't have the tools to check.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, HIRE AN ELECTRICIAN is the right answer, especially considering you are wary of other electrical issues. Sounds like they had some handyman or hack wire up this addition. I wonder what else is wrong structurally?

Comment: +1000 if I could. DIY isn't always the best option. Absolutely hire an electrician, especially given the OP's presumed knowledge level; even though you can often fumble through and correct (or appear to correct) the issue, you could do any number of things wrong or miss other things that cause a potentially harmful situation (e.g. an immediate shock hazard, a long-term fire hazard, etc.)

Comment: While this may be accurate, just about every question on a DIY site can be answered "get a professional." If a project is impractical for DIY (such as requiring specialized tools or a license to handle the equipment, e.g. HVAC coolant) then be sure to explain that. Otherwise, the answers we are looking for should educate someone how to do a task and then explain when they cannot do it themselves.

Comment: @BMitch, Again, I disagree. Sometimes, just sometimes, due to the nature of how a question is asked, and the obvious lack of experience/knowledge/equipment a poster has, and the sometimes dangerous or technical nature of a job, the simple answer is "hire a pro". And sometimes this is not easy to put in words with insulting someone or having them take offense. ...... I get that you people are trying to make this site like a technically accurate Wiki type of site with only certain types of questions and answers, but in the world of DIY that is sometimes not possible or prudent.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey Good answers on the site should be equally useful to the OP and others with similar questions that follow. Duplicate questions frequently occur and get closed with a pointer to the original post, the next person with the same question may have a different skill level. I'll post any other followups in meta or chat (don't want to clutter the comments).

Answer (score 1):

The most important device that won't work with a mis-wired outlet is a hot-side fuse or circuit breaker.  If hot and neutral are reversed and something within the device shorts to ground, none of the current will be flowing through the fuse or circuit breaker, so it won't be able to provide any protection.  Further, if too much current flows through the device from hot to neutral so the fuse/breaker does pop, it will still leave the device electrically connected to line potential.

While it's possible construct fuses or circuit breakers so than an excessive amount of current in either will disconnect both, such fuses and breakers are more expensive than units that only have to protect one or the other (note that it's important that the neutral *not* have a fuse, breaker, switch, or other disconnection device *unless* it is interlocked to ensure that the neutral wire will not disconnect without *also* disconnecting the hot wire; simply using separate breakers on hot and neutral is thus not a solution).

Answer (score 0):

I think pretty much any device will work in an incorrect neutral/hot-swapped outlet. Certainly any device that has a non-polarized plug will be totally fine. There are a number of safety features that are possible with a polarized plug but under normal circumstances the appliance can't tell which lead is hot and which is neutral, only that they are 120V apart.

(I assume you are talking exclusively about 120V outlets... for 240V outlets things are very different and swapping the neutral and one of the hot conductors is likely to fry the appliance.)

**EDIT**: I'm not saying that it's no big deal to swap the hot and neutral; you will be defeating several safety devices and potentially exposing yourself to electrocution. But for testing purposes, virtually everything should *function* fine either way.

Comment: If it will work, then why have a polarized plug?  If the device is a table-lamp, then you might want to be careful what part of the lamp you touch with bare hands, especially when changing the bulb.  Don't ask me how I know.

Comment: @jameslarge: There are very good safety reasons for having a polarized plug... you mention the lamp socket, that is definitely one. Other safety features that are possible with a polarized plug are a switched-hot lead inside the appliance, and positioning the hot and neutral wires so that it is less likely that any metal on the outside of the appliance becomes energized in the event of a loose wire inside. Swapping the neutral and hot defeats all of these safety devices and is definitely a bad idea. But under normal circumstances, virtually all appliances should *function* fine.

Comment: Agreed.  Functional, but scary.

Comment: I wasn't trying to advocate that it was fine, maybe I should've made that clear in my answer and I've edited to include that. Since the OP was trying to troubleshoot by plugging in things, I was just trying to say that everything should work OK and apparently there is some other issue.